# ng-repeat unable to parse arabic object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a json object based on arabic content as below

$scope.arabicContent = ["ردهة","قاعة الاجتماعات","مبرمجين الجوال","المدراء","المحاسبة","المحاسبة","المبرمجين‎","مطبخ‎ ‎","الطابق الأول‎"]

But ng-repeat is not able to parse/iterate this object at html side

```
<select name="meetingLocation" ng-model="data.meetingLocation">  <option ng-repeat="location in arabicContent" value="{{ location }}">{{ location }}</option> </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried to `ng-repeat` through the arabic array in a plunker and the error i got was  `[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed`. So, to me, it looks like there is text duplicated in that array (I could be wrong).

The solution to that error was to tell `ng-repeat` to track by index and not the content.

`ng-repeat="arabic in arabicContent track by $index"`

Here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uaIzf5Xty9o0GpIMdW0x?p=preview

Comment: You are right and I am able to fix this issue. Thanks